# How to auto-refresh KDE desktop?

Tags: kde, desktop, plasma, kde5, dolphin

If I add or remove files from my desktop on KDE by using, for instance, a terminal or Dolphin, the desktop isn't automatically refreshed. It's missing the new files and still shows the removed files. I can right-click the desktop and choose "Refresh Desktop". Is there any way to keep the desktop refreshing automatically?

Comment: Maybe kill `plasmashell` then restart it?

Comment: I know this is ancient, but AFAIK, it's still not fixed. Recently, they partially fixed it for changes done within Dolphin, but not for files changed externally such as at the CLI. You can run a bash script as a daemon... that emits an F5 using xdotool, but that gets messy if Dolphin isn't the currently active window. xdotool can detect that, but you need a pretty tight loop to get changes quickly and that may have other consequences.